# Alter confidence intervals in interaction plot in R

Tags: r, plot, interaction, confidence-interval

I am using the `sjPlot` package to plot interaction effects and would like to change the confidence intervals in the plots (e.g. from 95 to 90; and to generally have more flexibility), yet I'm unsure how. Here is the base code:

```
require(sjPlot); require(effects)
fit <- lm(weight ~ Diet * Time, data = ChickWeight)
sjp.int(fit, type = "eff", showCI = TRUE)
```

Any and all thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @aosmith: The help page says `plevel` changes do not apply to type="eff"

Comment: It appears to me that although the plevel parameter is passed to `sjp.eff.int` that it is basically ignored. It's not possible to pass the `confidence.level`-parameter to the `effects` functions within `sjp.eff.int` since there are no dots arguments in the formals lists. Might be possible to hack into it though. The code is avaialble.

Comment: I've changes the behaviour of the `showCI` argument, so you also may use a numeric value like `showCI = 0.85`; however, this currently only works for `type = "eff"`. For estimated marginal means, I'm not sure where the `lsmeans::lsmeans` functions accepts confidence level arguments. I'll commit the changes to GitHub tonight, so you may download the latest snapshot, if you like.